# Decimal to Hex - Cocoa/Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I need to convert some strings which have decimal content.
I want these contents in a string, in hex format...

How can I do it?

I tried to use NSScanner but this method seems to be a little bit huge to just make a dec-hex calculation?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: http://www.webelfin.com/webelfindesign/dechex.html

Answer (score 18):

If you know your string only contains a valid decimal number then the simplest way would be:

```
NSString *dec = @"254";
NSString *hex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%lX", 
                  (unsigned long)[dec integerValue]];
NSLog(@"%@", hex);
```

Comment: I was looking for the same thing, thanks for your solution. (Too bad that "Cindy Broutin" didn't valid your answer)